# prove that a function is an immersion

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

How I can show that $F \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $F(t)= (\cos (t), \sin(t))$ is an immersion? In my definition $F$ is an immersion if $\forall p$,$dF_p$ is injective.
I have compute $dF_p=(-\sin (t), \cos(t))$. But now?

Comment: $F$ is immersion iff $\text{rank}(dF_p)=1$. That is to say we just need to prove $\sqrt{(-\sin t)^2+(\cos t)^2}\not=0$.

Comment: $$(-\sin t\,,\,\cos t)=(-\sin(t+2k\pi)\,,\,\cos(t+2k\pi))\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\ldots$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Claim:** The linear map $dF_t:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, $x\mapsto (-\sin(t)x,\cos(t)x)$ is injective.

*Proof:* Since if $dF_t(x)=0$ for $x\not=0$, then $-\sin(t)x=0$ and $\cos(t)x=0$. But then $\cos(t)=\sin(t)=0$.

$\sin$ and $\cos$ have no common zeros. Therefore $\ker dF_t = 0$.$\square$

In other words, the matrix $(-\sin(t),\cos(t))$ always has rank $1$.

This implies that $F$ is an immersion.

Comment: The OP says it computed $\;dF_p=(-\sin t,\cos t)\;$ . How is this injective?? Maybe I'm missing some point here...

Comment: @DonAntonio $p=t$ is the constant base point here. $dF_p$ is the linear map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ given by multiplication with the matrix $(-\sin t,\cos t)$. We are *not* discussing injectivity of the map $t\mapsto dF_t$. This is of course not injective.

Comment: Ok, but then it is not true, apparently, what the OP wrote: that the map he calls $\;dF_p\;$ is injective, since that map is way non-injective.

Comment: @DonAntonio: No, what the OP wrote is fine. He says that $F$ is an immersion, if *for all* $p$, the map $dF_p$ is injective. Note please, how $p=t$ is *constant*.

Comment: @TooOldForMath thanks for your explanation. But I have a question, the differential in a point is a map that goes to the tangent space of the domain in the tangent space of the codomani. In this case we can identify $T_p\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}^2$...if I would work with the definition $dF_p(v)(f)=v(f \circ F)$ where f a function in the stalk at p, and v is a tangent vector how i can procede?

Comment: @andreasvr Please make a new question.

Comment: @andreasvr: The point is that the derivations at $p$ act as directional derivatives at $p$. Since your space is here one dimensional this is just the usual derivative at $p$ multiplied by a scalar.

Comment: @andreasvr: I have answered your follow up question, please read and see if you understand.