# Tangent vector to a curve on a manifold

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, manifolds

If one has a curve $\sigma : (-1,1) \rightarrow M$, where $M$ is a smooth manifold, the tangent vector in $\sigma(0)$ is usually defined as
$$ \sigma'(0) (f) = \dfrac{d f \circ \sigma}{dt} \Big|_0,$$
where $f \in C^{\infty}(\sigma(0))$.

I would expect this to give the usual derivative definition in the case $M = \mathbb R^2,$ however I don't see how to drop the dependency of the derivative from the germ $f$. In fact in $\mathbb R ^2$ one obtains
$$\sigma'(0) (f) = \dfrac{d f \circ \sigma}{dt} \Big|_0 = \dfrac{d f}{dx} \Big|_{\sigma(0)} \sigma_1'(0) + \dfrac{d f}{dy}\Big|_{\sigma(0)} \sigma_2'(0), $$
which does not give the original concept of derivative (i.e. $(\sigma_1'(0), \sigma_2'(0))$) if, for example, $f(x,y) = x$ and $\sigma(t) = (0,t)$.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653280/prove-that-this-function-is-an-immersion/653300#653300) I explained this today in slightly different, but analogous situation.

Comment: It should give you the directional derivative of $f$ in direction of $\sigma'$. What do you mean by the original concept of derivative.

Comment: According to the standard definition of derivative in multivariable calculus books, $\sigma'(0)(f)$ should be $\nabla f(\sigma(0)) \cdot \sigma'(0)$, which is exactly what you wrote on the right-hand side.

Comment: @Semsem I expect to obtain $(\sigma_1'(0), \sigma_2'(0))$. I guess it is not what I should expect? The notation $\sigma'$ indeed confuses me.

Comment: $\sigma'(0)$ stands for a derivative of the form $\sigma'_1 (0)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\sigma'_2 (0)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tangent vector $\sigma'(0)$ of a curve $\sigma(t)$ becomes a derivative operator of the form  $\sigma'_1 (0)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\sigma'_2 (0)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and so
$$\sigma'(0) (f) = \dfrac{d f \circ \sigma}{dt} \Big|_0 = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \Big|_{\sigma(0)} \sigma_1'(0) + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big|_{\sigma(0)} \sigma_2'(0)$$
For the last example you gave it is just a derivative of $f$ in $y$ direction i.e. $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big|_{\sigma(0)} $  since $\sigma$ is the equation of $y$ axis and $\sigma'(0)=(0,1)$